# how can I use mysql variable for my sql?

Tags: mysql

how can I use mysql variable for my sql?
sometimes I have to write some very long sql joining several tables to get results. I want to set some vars to shorter my main sql, how to set vars in mysql?

```
// this is the normal sql
select 
    a.name,a.money,b.mail
from
    (select name, sum(money) from moneys group by name) as a  
    left join (select name ,email from persons) as b on a.name = b.name


// I want to using variable to make my sql shorter and easy to understand, how to write?
select 
    a.name,a.money,b.mail
from
    var_a  
    left join var_b
```

Comment: Try reading on using SQL Views for your problem. You can parse your select query into a view and use the view to join as a normal table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to be rude, but this one comes up pretty easily from some searches... all leading to the MySQL manual page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Not sure what you were searching on, but hope that helps... it has examples and all.